# specman cant connect multiple ports to a single port

Tags: specman

I found out that Specman has a limitations when connecting multiple ports to a single port: only method port broadcast is supported. Is the only way to overcome it is to write a dedicated unit that splits each port to several ports?

Answer (score 0):

some ports are one-to-many.
for example - simple port. you can connect one instance of out_simple port, to many instance of simple_port.

what kind of ports do you try to use?
and do you want e-to-e or e to another language?

Comment: I try to connect buffer_port from one unit to another one. its not one to many but one that reads from one and writes to another.